solve the overlapping issue of switch ports in mininet
0
I build a topology with writing python script and i want to create some paths to connect some hosts but there are overlaps between some paths. what is the proper command that i can use to create paths by solving the issue of overlapping in the ports? also my topology should not have controler
I tried this commands but didn't work:(I provide just one related to one switch)
1- sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=1,action:output=3 sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=3,action:output=1
2- sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=1,ip,nw_src=10.0.0.1,action:output=3 sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=3,1p,nw_src=10.0.0.3,action:output=1
3- sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=1,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01,actions:output=3 sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow ES1 in_port=3,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:03,actions:output=1
none of these three options work and the proplem was either when i tried to create the new paths the old one where overrided or the path haven't been created
